# identify the user from cross-site post request

Tags: javascript, security, cross-domain

In my app, I will provide my client a javascript plugin, which will collect some HTML data and send to my server. I wonder what's the best way to identify my client. Say someone copied the javascript and put into his website. A similar case is the live chat plugin.

Comment: I'm going to go with:  This will never be even remotely possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really your questions it is not very clear to me. I am monitoring it from the beginning, so as no one answers I can say the following:

1.- If your javascript plugin is to plug in websites, as a jquery plugin, then you don't be sure about nothing because the code can easily be modified to remove any security procedure.
2.- If your javascript plugin is to plug in browsers, as a FF addon. Well, indeed can be modified too, but in the most of cases you can track simply with cookies or a login procedure.

Said that I think that if the case is the first (plug in websites) you could identify the websites asking for a authentication token stored in the server's website (requested by AJAX) and add it to the HTML data that is send to your server.

Hopefully you can understand my Emglizch :) and do not say pure garbage.